# Making 'permanent' changes to Django Model objects

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm getting the details about the songs for a particular DJ from the Beatport API as follows.

```
if not get_obj_or_none(Song, name__iexact=song_name, artist=dj):
    s = Song(song_id=song['id'], name=song_name, artist=dj, release_date=song['releaseDate'])
    s.save()
```

This adds the songs not currently in the Song model to the Song model.

Now a lot of songs have some discrepancies in the Song name field and a lot of them are repeated because of small differences in the song name. It isn't possible to write a code to differentiate among each of them. I can edit them using the admin but i need to rerun this code from time to time to update the Song model with new songs. How can I edit or delete some specific Song objects without them being readded when I run the code again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try introducing an additional field on your `Song` model for storing a *normalized* version of the song's name. Before storing a new song, you would then check whether or not the normalized name matches the normalized name of any existing song in the database.

Normalization could be done by a combination of

- lower-casing the song name
- replacing spaces with (single) underscores
- replacing hyphens with underscores
- removing any special characters (square brackets, parentheses etc)
- replacing dots with underscores.

This should eliminate a large portion of duplicates.

Code examples for the operations listed above:

- `song_name.lower()`
- `re.sub(' +', '_', song_name)`
- `re.sub('-+', '_', song_name)`
- `re.sub('[\(\)\[\]]', '', song_name)`
- `re.sub('\.+', '_', song_name)`

Operations replacing spaces/hyphens/dots with underscores can of course be combined.

Comment: This may remove a large portion of duplicates but there still will remain a few amount of entries that will be correct. Plus there are some entries which I want to delete all together. How can I deal with that?

Comment: @JaskaranRana That depends on whether or not it is acceptable for you to have duplicates in the system or not. You could e.g. introduce a `BooleanField` called `duplicate` on your `Song` model and set that to `True` using the Django admin after running your script. Since duplicates would also have their `normalized_name` field set, these songs would not be added again when you run the script again. If necessary, you could then show only those songs which are *not* marked as "duplicate" by using appropriate filters wherever you are displaying the songs in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a second model that holds the synonymous song names, something like:

```
class SongSynonym(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(...)
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song)
```

and check for existence of either a `Song` or `SongSynonym` before creating a new `Song`